# Jackson not able to parse json with spaces

Tags: json, jersey, jackson, grizzly

I use Jackson as the JSON mapper in a Grizzly server. To enable Jackson I just add `register(Jackson.feature)` in `ResourceConfig`. It works great as my Java POJO objects in my JAXRS APIs are automatically mapped from JSON inputs as HTTP content with `application/json` content type.

For example, `{"name":"test1"}` is automatically mapped to a class

```java
class Name {
   private String name;
   public Name() {}
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

The string `name` has value `test1`.

However, if I add a space anywhere in the JSON, Jackson is not able to map it to the class. The Grizzly returns `404` status code.

For example, if JSON is `{"name":"test 1"}` or `{   "name": "test1"  }`, the mapper does not work even though these are valid JSON. For the first case, I am able to get it working by replacing the space with `\u0020`.

Is there any Jackson settings that enable these JSON to be mapped to Java class?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Jackson has no trouble with whitespace.  We do it all the time.  However, we occasionally get bug reports from users that send non-breaking spaces by mistake.  Are you sure it is a space and not a non-breaking space?  Some programs like Skype, Outlook do weird things with text when you copy-paste.  Save your request to a file and get a hex dump like:

```
od -tx1 myfile
```

look for the 20 hex space and make sure it is not c2 a0 which is the non-breaking space.